# How to create nested list using special condition in python

Tags: python, list, nested, conditional-statements

I really appreciate an answer for my problem.
So problem: I have a list

```
Plist=[[x1,y2,str_1],[x2,y2,str_1],[x3,y3,str_1],[x4,y4,str_2],[x5,y5,str_2]]
```

and would like to convert it into a nested list (would avoid dict now):

```
newPlist=[[[x1,y2,str_1],[x2,y2,str_1],[x3,y3,str_1]],[[x4,y4,str_2],[x5,y5,str_2]]]
```

I know how to sort it out based on length, yet cannot figure it out if I have a special condition (in my case `Plist[][2]`)
What I have tried so far:
grouped data:

```
for elt, items in groupby(Plist, itemgetter(2)):

print elt, item  
    for i in items:  
        print i
```

and I got stuck what to write after that

```
 newPlist=[]  
 newPlist.append(???)
```

Reading the forum, I feel this is something basic, yet I just cannot figure it out. I found panda and numpy, but for special reason, I cannot use them.
Thank you very much in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `list` on each `items`:

```
newPlist.append(list(items))
```

For example, the first `list(items)` will evaluate to:

```
[['x1', 'y2', 'str_1'], ['x2', 'y2', 'str_1'], ['x3', 'y3', 'str_1']]
```

and so on.

Note that since each `items` is a generator, you will need to remove the printing loop to avoid consuming the generator's content, otherwise `list(items)` will just be an empty list.

Comment: Thank you, it almost does, what I want, yet it somehow cuts the first item.

Comment: So practically I get this back:[[['x2', 'y2', 'str_1'], ['x3', 'y3', 'str_1']], [['x5', 'y5', 'str_2']]]

Comment: Sorry, it works like charm! Forgot to remove the second loop.